# Searching and smart group for multiple event types

Tags: advanced-search

I created a smart group through advanced search maybe 1 year ago for all contacts that had participated in an Event Type A or B or C. If I remember correctly it was very simple because the "Event Type" field in Advanced Search allowed multiple types to be selected. We now want to include Event Type D but when I go to edit the advanced search, it only allows a single type to be selected. Has the select widget for Event Type in Advance Search been changed to single select? Any ideas on how to now do a search for multiple event types?

Comment: What you might have done was create three smart groups separately from single event type searches, then combine on advanced search using the groups field there which does allow multiple. When editing the smart group what's in the groups field, in the basic criteria section?

Comment: Thanks, @Demerit for the idea but, no, I did not do that. This is the only smart group we have. When I go to edit the smart group search, it has no criteria whatsoever so, now it is just returning all contacts in the database.

Comment: If you go to /civicrm/api3, and then for Entity choose "SavedSearch", then click the Execute button at the bottom it will output some gobbledygook. Can you edit your question post and copy and paste that in there (it will be too big for a comment). If you put three backticks before and after it then it will format properly (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Again, thanks @Demerit. Through the API I was able to see what had happened and figure out a way forward. I had created the original search based on the event names. However, then others started naming events with no regard to the protocol I had developed so that no longer worked, which I should have known would happen.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense.

Comment: Daniel - can you now Answer your own Question as Stack Exchange likes to know that answers happen

Answer (score 1):

Using the API3 interface I was able to see the information I needed to work though this problem. See the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there has been a request since 2017 to request this functionality at [Multiselect for Event Type in Advanced Search](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/465).

Answer (score 1):

With the new search interface [SearchKit](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/search-kit) now it's possible to get this type of smart group in an alternative and easy way to advanced search.